# Why dont all my textviews update with 1 button clicks? Requires multiple clicks

Tags: android

public class Calculator extends Activity {

```
String[] measurement;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
```

Comment: Please parse that down to only the relevant code.

Comment: did u try hard coding some text values and setting them on button click

Comment: @PulkitSethi do you mean trying value_gram_profit.setText(
"test
"); instead of value_gram_profit.setText(Double.toString(new_gram_profit));

Comment: yes, i reckon if you are changing something in the spinner then spinner posts the change for its item selected listener, i am just guessing as not sure how u testing the above

Comment: That empty `else` statement looks suspicious - as it is, you'll never be able to tell if the `else` gets hit or not... If you're confident it doesn't, chuck a `throw new RuntimeException("Else got hit!")` in it and see what happens. Or, even better, just attach a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: @MH. I just removed the else condition, still the same

Comment: log the value of spinner_value

Comment: @chromedome: removing the else effectively changes nothing... Stepping through the code with a debugger is still my recommendation.

Comment: @PulkitSethi - I removed the spinner to see if thats the cause, still the same

Comment: hmm can u put your layout xml

Comment: mate, you are reusing your ids u need to change your xml to use distinct everywhere. I know the android site states otherwise but trust me dont do it. change all ids to be unique even if they are in different table rows its calculating views from top level

Comment: @PulkitSethi - all the textviews that were getting updated, had unique ids, but now I have updated it to all textviews having unique ids, but it hasnt changed anything

Comment: @PulkitSethi - my calculations and variables were all messed up! I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `invalidate` after calling `setText`.

Comment: eighth_amt_int = user_amount_db / 3.5;
 eighth_amt_int = Math.round(eighth_amt_int*1e2)/1e2;
 value_eighth_amt.setText(Double.toString(eighth_amt_int));
 value_eighth_amt.invalidate();
 value_gram_amt.setText(Double.toString(new_gram_amt));
 value_gram_amt.invalidate();
 value_gram_sale.setText(Double.toString(new_gram_sale));     
 value_gram_sale.invalidate();
 value_gram_profit.setText(Double.toString(new_gram_profit));
 value_gram_profit.invalidate();

Comment: this didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i'd suggest using an integer to hold position of selected spinner item and comparing that; rather than .equals("GRAM") - strings can sometimes get a bit tricky.
Secondly, comment out the toast in else statement; make sure that the if loop is actually being executed. 
Lastly, try
 value_eighth_amt.setText(eighth_amt_int + " "); for all the textviews.

Comment: Also, check your XML layout file. The java code seems proper; there might be something in the xml that could be causing you problems

Comment: I removed the spinner condition and moved the code inside it to directly inside the button listener just for debugging. I also checked my XML, seems fine and tried the new way of updating the textviews. Doesnt seem anything has changed.